# whats kind of data is this sending across?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I am trying to using postman type app to send a json post from this form, was wondering what kind of data is it sending across?

```
<%= simple_form_for @scooties_coupon do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :first_name %>
  <%= f.input :surname %>
  <%= f.input :occupation%>

  <%= f.input :email, input_html: { autocomplete: 'email' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is a form submission that submits first_name,surname,occupation and email

Answer (score 0):

Your form collects four inputs: `first_name`, `surname`, `occupation`, `email`. And finally sends it the server. You can try it using `cURL` in your console.

```
curl -d "first_name=FirstName&surname=YourSurname&occupation=Dev&email=email" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data
```

Change the URL by yours.

Hope it helps clarify your doubts.

Comment: It seems he's binding the form to a model, so I believe your example should take in account the namespace (not sure about the name generated though):

curl -d "scooty_coupon[first_name]=FirstName&scooty_coupon[surname]=YourSurname&scooty_coupon[occupation]=Dev&scooty_coupon[email]=email" -X POST http://localhost:3000/data